# What is the best multiple monitors app for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

What is the best app for supporting multiple monitors in Windows 7?  Ultra mon was perfect in Vista and XP but I don't think it works with Windows 7 yet.  The main features I'm looking for are:

- Taskbar for each monitor with only the apps that are running there.  This might not be doable based on how the Windows 7 taskbar works now.
- A button next to Minimize to send the window to the other monitor
- Separate wallpapers for each monitor

Comment: Windows+Shift+[Left/Right] should move your window between monitors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Ultramon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) now supports Windows 7 as well, but if you're having problems, check out [DisplayFusion](http://www.binaryfortress.com/displayfusion/)

Comment: I use Ultramon on all my laptops ..

Comment: I'm using DisplayFusion but can't seem to easily move windows from one monitor to the other.  I think it runs on middle mouse click but that stopped working for some reason.  It also doesn't have any taskbar upgrades.  Is that only because I'm using the free version?

Comment: @AndyMcKenna: The middle-click window movement is an option, make sure it is enabled in the settings. The multi-monitor taskbar is only available to Pro users (only $20).

Comment: UltraMon seems dead here in 2011.. DisplayFusion is still going strong, and is currently a superior product.

Answer (score 6):

Display Fusion takes care of the wallpaper stuff.

Comment: It will also take care of the multi-monitor taskbar and the button next to Minimize to send the window to the other monitor (version 3.1).

Answer (score 6):

Here is a full list of shortcuts for Windows 7 (from [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5132073/the-best-new-windows-7-keyboard-shortcuts)):

- Win+Home: Clear all but the active window
- Win+Space: All windows become transparent so you can see through to the desktop
- Win+Up arrow: Maximize the active window
- Win+Down arrow: Minimize the window/Restore the window if it's maximized
- Win+Left/Right arrows: Dock the window to each side of the monitor (If you've got dual monitors, adding Shift to the mix (e.g., Win+Shift+Right arrow) will move the window to the adjacent monitor.)
- Win+T: Focus and scroll through items on the taskbar.
- Win+P: Adjust presentation settings for your display
- Win+(+/-): Zoom in/out
- Shift+Click a taskbar item: Open a new instance of that application

Answer (score 6):

[DisplayFusion](http://www.binaryfortress.com/displayfusion/)** has everything you're asking about: taskbar, window buttons and wallpaper management (including on-line image sources). It also supports the look-and-feel of the Windows 7 taskbar (including pinning and previews), so it blends in with the OS.

(**I'm probably biased, because I'm the developer)

Comment: Thanks, Jon.  I'm doing the 1 month free trial of the Pro version and like that the price is half of Ultramon's single license.  The taskbar is working great so far.

Comment: Just got DF for myself recently. It's nice, and they read their support forums! :)