# Maximize a window on to dual monitors in Windows?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I have dual monitors and I want to span my current window so that it appears as one giant window on both monitors. Does anyone know how to do this natively in Windows?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/3004/what-is-the-best-multiple-monitors-app-for-windows-7?rq=1

Answer (score 22):

**Jeff Axelrod has a [great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9830200/470749) that uses [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/).**

He maps the <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> combination to maximize a window across all displays, which compliments Windows 7's <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> hotkey, which maximizes the selected window in one monitor.

Here is his code (thanks Jeff!):

```
;Shift + Windows + Up (maximize a window across all displays) https://stackoverflow.com/a/9830200/470749
+#Up::
    WinGetActiveTitle, Title
    WinRestore, %Title%
   SysGet, X1, 76
   SysGet, Y1, 77
   SysGet, Width, 78
   SysGet, Height, 79
   WinMove, %Title%,, X1, Y1, Width, Height
return
```

Comment: Shift + Windows + Up does not work on my Windows 10 setup with two screens and two different graphics drivers. Still potentially useful to others.

Comment: Works fine on Windows 10 with a single graphics card. I could not get this to work with a Citrix window though. It opened the window over 2 monitors fine, but then when I clicked into the window, Citrix took control and resized the window back to one monitor.

Comment: I subtracted 40 from Height in the WinMove line in order to still be able to see the Task Bar and Start Menu button

Comment: On Windows 11, this combination defaults to maximizing the height of a window (regardless if its between 2 screens), without going fullscreen on either or both screens. This is actually exactly what I was looking for, since I work with an ultra widescreen monitor that I treat as 2 separate screens.

Answer (score 17):

In contrast with what others are saying, here is a free, working solution that maximises the window which is under the mouse.

(Credits go to the guy who wrote these amazing 'autoit' functions - I just wrote the bit which uses them.)

Download autoit and install it (free software):

http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Create a .au3 file.

Paste this inside:

```
#include <misc.au3>
#include <Array.au3>
HotKeySet('{ESC}', '_Exit')

Global $WinText, $OldMouse[2], $NewMouse[2], $Windows, $x, $MyWin, $MyCoords

$NewMouse = MouseGetPos()
$title = _GetWin()
WinSetState($MyWin,"",@SW_RESTORE)
WinMove($MyWin,"",0,0,3840,1165)

Func _GetWin()
    Local $Coords
    ToolTip("")
    $Mouse = MouseGetPos()
    $OldMouse = $Mouse
    $Windows = _WinList()
    ;_ArrayDisplay($Windows, "")
    For $x = 1 To UBound($Windows)-1
        $Coords = WinGetPos($Windows[$x][0], "")
        If $Coords = -4 Then ExitLoop
        If IsArray($Coords) Then
            If $Mouse[0] >= $Coords[0] And $Mouse[0] <= ($Coords[0]+$Coords[2]) And $Mouse[1] >= $Coords[1] And $Mouse[1] <= ($Coords[1]+$Coords[3]) Then ExitLoop
        EndIf   
    Next
    If $x = UBound($Windows) Then $x -= 1
    $MyWin =  $Windows[$x][0]
    $Control = _MouseGetCtrlInfo()
    $Return = $Windows[$x][0] & @CRLF & $Control 
    Return $Return
EndFunc 

Func _WinList()
    Local $WinListArray[1][2]
    $var = WinList()
    For $i = 1 to $var[0][0]
        If $var[$i][0] <> "" AND IsVisible($var[$i][1]) Then
            Redim $WinListArray[UBound($WinListArray) + 1][2]
            $WinListArray[UBound($WinListArray)-1][0] = $var[$i][0]
            $WinListArray[UBound($WinListArray)-1][1] = $var[$i][1]
        EndIf
    Next
    Return $WinListArray
EndFunc

Func IsVisible($handle)
  If BitAnd( WinGetState($handle), 2 ) Then 
    Return 1
  Else
    Return 0
  EndIf
EndFunc

Func _Exit()
    Exit
EndFunc 

Func _MouseGetCtrlInfo()  ; get ID, Classe and Text of a control
    Global $hWin = WinGetHandle($MyWin)
    Global $sClassList = WinGetClassList($hWin)
    Local $sSplitClass = StringSplit(StringTrimRight($sClassList, 1), @LF)
    Local $aMPos = MouseGetPos()
    ;_ArrayDisplay($sSplitClass, "")
    $MyCoords = ClientToScreen($hWin)
    For $iCount = UBound($sSplitClass) - 1 To 1 Step - 1
        Local $nCount = 0
        If $sSplitClass[$iCount] = "WorkerW" Then ContinueLoop
        While 1
            $nCount += 1
            $aCPos = ControlGetPos($hWin, '', $sSplitClass[$iCount] & $nCount)
            If @error Then ExitLoop
            $hCtrlWnd = ControlGetHandle ($hWin, "", $sSplitClass[$iCount] & $nCount)
            If IsArray($aCPos) Then
                If $aMPos[0] >= ($MyCoords[0]+$aCPos[0]) And $aMPos[0] <= ($MyCoords[0]+$aCPos[0] + $aCPos[2]) _
                    And $aMPos[1] >= ($MyCoords[1]+$aCPos[1]) And $aMPos[1] <= ($MyCoords[1]+$aCPos[1] + $aCPos[3]) Then
                    $aReturn = DllCall('User32.dll', 'int', 'GetDlgCtrlID', 'hwnd', $hCtrlWnd)
                    If @error Then Return "Err"
                    $Text = ControlGetText($hWin, '', $sSplitClass[$iCount] & $nCount)
                    If StringInStr($Text, @LF) Then $Text = "demasiado largo"
                    If IsArray($aReturn) Then Return 'ControlID: ' & $aReturn[0] & @CRLF & 'ClassNameNN: ' & $sSplitClass[$iCount] & $nCount &  @CRLF & "Text: " & $Text
                EndIf      
            EndIf
        WEnd
    Next
    ;_ArrayDisplay($sSplitClass, "")
    Return "No Ctrl"
EndFunc

Func ClientToScreen($hWnd)    ; get client area of a win relative to the screan
    Local $Point, $aRes[2]
    Local $cX, $cY
    $Point = DllStructCreate("int;int")
    DllStructSetData($Point, 1, $cX)
    DllStructSetData($Point, 1, $cY)
    DllCall("User32.dll", "int", "ClientToScreen", "hwnd", $hWnd, "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($Point))
    $aRes[0] = DllStructGetData($Point, 1)
    $aRes[1] = DllStructGetData($Point, 2)
    Return $aRes
EndFunc
```

Then change the line

WinMove($MyWin,"",0,0,3840,1165)

to the values of your liking.

Then you can create a windows shortcut to this file, right click it->properties, and assign a shortcut (e.g. CTRL+ALT+UP).

Most likely you will find that you will need to repeat the procedure and create a second file to restore the window to a small size.

Hope this helps

Comment: Love it!  I was going to use the NVidia mosaic, but the monitors I wanted to split across where from two separate graphics cards, and couldn't recable because of KVM not doing VGA.  Only gotchya - I wasn't able to get the keyboard shortcut to work directly off a shortcut to the .au3 file.  I was able to get a keyboard shortcut to work off a shortcut to a batch script that called the au3 script though.

Comment: Indeed the shortcut method does not work, unless the script file is placed on your desktop.

Comment: For those having more than 2 monitors, the 0,0 in the line WinMove($MyWin,"",0,0,3840,1165) represents the coordinates of the starting point, so one may maximise across any amount of screens by changing these numbers accordingly.

Comment: I have to create a shortcut to this maximize.au3 in Win 10, and the properties of the shortcut let me assign a key-shortcut; not batch needed.

Comment: @nikos this script works for me but I cannot figure out the syntax for the windows position; seems my 0,0 is somewhere "near" the top left of my main monitor but not quite. Also my second monitor is to the left of my main monitor (and the script seems to allow for such, but I do not yet read AutoIt syntax). But the script is opening my program to the right of my main monitor (where there is "nothing"). I tried hooking to a negative value (-1920,0) but that did not work, negative numbers refused. Please advise. Your answer is a joy, will be my solution for many programs, just need to learn more

Comment: @nikos thanks, I worked it out: the problem was with the 125% maginification that Windows puts on my screens (for my old eyes) and with AutoIt which did not like my syntax once and had applied a comment-tag to the line where the window-size is defined. Now this is working on my machine and I love you (technically speaking). Thanks!!!

Answer (score 12):

Use **[Dual Monitor Tools](http://dualmonitortool.sourceforge.net/)**: it's a set of **free tools** do manage multiple screens setup.

In the **[Swap screen](http://dualmonitortool.sourceforge.net/swapscreen.html)** tool you can assign a hotkey to the "Supersize active window" so you can maximize it to occupy all the screens.

Comment: Excellent program with sane defaults (all disabled) that does exactly what I was looking for, coming from Ultramon. A hint: the hotkey to "Supersize active window" acts like a toggle. Hitting it again restores the window.

Comment: Does not work with VNC Viewer from RealVNC. The Dual Monitor Tools hotkey correctly maximizes the VNC Viewer window across both monitors, but when I select the "Full screen mode" option in VNC Viewer to remove the window frame the window pops back to only occupy a single monitor.

Comment: Does not work with Citrix. It fills 2 monitors, but then when I select full screen mode it goes back to a single monitor.

Answer (score 9):

I found a way to do this without any software or code. It isn't automatic or perfect, but is easy and works well enough.

1. Windows + left or right arrow key to snap the window to half a monitor on the far edge of the two monitors
2. Grab the edge of the window and drag it across both monitors to the far side

Comment: this is very clever to use the built-in features of windows and works perfectly for setups with two monitors with same resolution/size side by side.

Answer (score 4):

A bit late but if using Intel integrated graphics you can open the Intel graphics control panel, select display menu and from there choose multiple displays and choose "Collage" this will let you choose which monitors you would like to extend across along with some other choices.

Here's a screenshot of it enabled:

[image: Heres a screenshot of it enabled]

Answer (score 3):

If you have an nVidia video card:

1. Right-click on the desktop, and click "NVIDIA Control Panel"
2. At the bottom of the list of tasks, under Workstation, is "Set up Mosaic". Click it.
3. In the right pane, click the checkbox next to "Enable Mosaic"
4. Under Displays, put checkmarks next to the monitors you want to combine.
5. Under Configuration, select what topology you want (side-by-side, vertical..)
6. At the bottom-right of the screen, click "Apply"

Now, when you click the Maximize button, it'll cover both monitors.
Your taskbar will also cover both monitors.  If that bugs you, try dragging it to the left of the monitor so it becomes vertical (this works better if you make the icons small and use 'never combine').

Comment: "Set up Mosaic" no longer available in NVIDIA Control Panel 8.1.940.0 from 2020.

Comment: @AxelBregnsbo I am using that version (8.1.940.0) and still see the option, even though this is a different computer than the one I used before. Maybe it depends on the particular card or driver (this one is a Quadro K1100M with driver version 425.53). The feature doesn't seem to actually work for me anymore, though...

Comment: you need quadro or nvs

Answer (score 2):

I use a free utility to do so, VirtualScreenMaximizer:

http://virtualscreenmax.codeplex.com/releases/view/20213

You can customize the shortcuts to use for maximizing and restoring, and it will expand the window over the taskbar when maximizing.

Answer (score 1):

Click and drag, otherwise you can use your advanced graphics card to configure the monitors to act as one large screen.

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows 7 I'm able to drag the window so that it covers both screens. If you right click your desktop and chose "screen resolution", you have to chose "extend these displays" under "multiple displays". If you close the window again it should remember size and position.

Comment: That's true, I'm looking for a solution where you can easily maximize the window to both monitors with either a shortcut or something like that.

Comment: aren't  you able to do that by simply dragging the window title-bar  to the to the top of the screen

Comment: @subanki - no, that'll just maximize the window on the current monitor (the one you "bumped")

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still trying to do this using [autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) I managed do this using this code:

```
HotKeySet("^+{UP}", "Resize_Window") ; CTRL+SHIFT+UP
While 1
    Sleep(1000)
WEnd
Func Resize_Window()
    WinSetState("[ACTIVE]","",@SW_RESTORE)
    WinMove("[ACTIVE]","",0,0,_WinAPI_GetSystemMetrics($SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN),_WinAPI_GetSystemMetrics($SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN))
EndFunc
```

Comment: After including WinAPI.au3 and WindowsConstants.au3 this works.

Answer (score 0):

I use this workaround with Sizer ([homepage](http://www.brianapps.net/sizer/)) - its small freeware utility allows you to set predefined windows size by right-click in Window stretch area.

Just create profile set:

- Width = sum of monitors widths
- Height = Monitor height - taskbar height (= 40)
- Move to = Top left.

Then just right click to right-bottom end of the Window and select the profile.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Turns out this is from something called nView Desktop Manager from NVidia. Available for Quadro and NVS products on Windows 7 to 10. "https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/nview/149_77/nview-win7-win10-x64-149-77-driver/". Original answer below.

While researching this, (to figure out how I did it by accident a few times), I figured out an answer. 
Hold "shift" key when you click the maximize button if you have Windows 10. For me, it maximizes across all 3 of my monitors, all of which are different sizes, different connections (vga,dvi,dvi to display port adapter), and 1 of them is on a KVM switch. The height is set to the smallest of the 3 monitors so things line up across all. I assume it would work as expected for same size monitors.

Note: I don't know if this is a recent feature or been around a while. Haven't found anything about it online.

Comment: This does not work on any of my Windows 10 machines.  I suspect this works due to third-party software you have installed.

Comment: Yup, looks like it is something called nView Desktop Manager from NVidia. Available for Quadro and NVS products on Windows 7 to 10.
https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/nview/149_77/nview-win7-win10-x64-149-77-driver/

Comment: Ramhound, thank you, good point.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 11, unmaximise your window, then while pressing Shift + Windows keys, click to maximise.
Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Right click on toolbar of windows, select Restore, then resize it on both screens.

Answer (score -1):

i was able to get F11-maximized windows over 3 unified displays using NVidia Mosaic with a Quadro GPU. I was NOT able to do it using autoit / autohotkey / dual monitor tools / virtualscreenmaximizer / intel collage. With these you can get a maximal size window but not a gui-less maximized window.