# Windows 7 shortcut -> make current window cover all monitors?

Tags: windows-7, hotkeys

When I run a diff or merge, I would like the window to span all monitors so I can see the entirety of both files at once. Is there a windows 7 shortcut to do this?

Edit: Since the hotkey doesn't exist, how about something that is light and quick to setup that runs a configurable script to do this?  Free is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many utilities that add this functionality to Windows.

Before installing a third-party utility, check if your video-card software has built-in support for spanning over multiple monitors.

Otherwise here are some utilities :

[**VirtualScreenMaximizer**](http://www.codeplex.com/VirtualScreenMax/Releas/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=20213) (free), review by lifehacker [available](http://lifehacker.com/5104416/virtualscreenmaximizer-maximizes-windows-across-multiple-monitors).

This SuperUser answer for [How can you maximize a window on to dual monitors in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/a/422152/8672) contains an [**autoit**](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) script for maximizing over two monitors.

[**DisplayFusion**](http://www.displayfusion.com/), free version and pro version ($25).
The free version might contain this feature.

**Actual Multiple Monitors**, free version and pro version ($29.95).
It's unclear whether the free version contains this feature.
Its "Maximize to Desktop" function can maximize to more than two monitors :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There isn't. Due to the many different possible monitor configurations a feature like this is impossible to implement properly (thus, I claim that it wasn't implemented).

For example, look what happens when I maximize Notepad over all screens:

[image]

In the middle, on the main screen, the top and bottom are cut off because the outer screens are simply higher.

That being said, I actually used exactly the functionality you describe to make that screenshot. But I used the functionality provided by [UtltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) (commercial).

It has a [maximize to desktop](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/windows.asp) functionality: [image]