# Can a program window be maximized across multi-displays?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, multiple-monitors

I would like to be able to choose whether to **maximize in the current monitor** or **maximize to span over all monitors**.

Is there a built-in feature (with a shortcut) or a program that can be used to maximize a window to span over multiple displays and fill them?

**edit** 
Preferences

- not dependent on hardware
- provides visual feedback that it is installed, only where it is necessary (eg. next to the maximize button, and in the window's right-click [control menu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

I forgot to use my homework but, as an old-fashioned **Windows XP** user, and encouraged by [CharlieRB](https://superuser.com/users/97028/charlierb), I [DDGed](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=multi-monitor+maximize) 'multi-monitor maximize' on the all-featureful *duckduckgo.com* and read that [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) could do it, although that is a **paid** one. (I need this single feature sometimes but not often enough to justify a payment for the pack.) The Q [How can you maximize a window on to dual monitors in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/186633/how-can-you-maximize-a-window-on-to-dual-monitors-in-windows-7) suggests an autoit script with *Windows 7*, however does it do visual indicators and buttons? While I'm a fan of keyboard, I also use the mouse (actually I tend to like to use them in a mutually exclusive way). Looking for the open-source (openness I prefer) [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/ultramon/?platform=windows&license=opensource) on the good *alternativeto.net*, only [Dual Monitor Tools](http://dualmonitortool.sourceforge.net/) by [Gerald Evans](http://sourceforge.net/u/gne/profile/) looked like it could have this feature but it seems it doesn't. Since I already use [Filebox eXtender](http://www.hyperionics.com/files/index.asp) and [DM2](http://dm2.sourceforge.net/) and greatest-thing-since-wheel [FlashFolder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flashfolder/) , I realize how important for me it is that these provide **on-context** (ie. as in *on-topic*) *visual feedback* of they being installed, what I think the autoit script is lacking.

I use an *Nvidia* card at home and an *[integrated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_graphics#Integrated_graphics_solutions) Intel* card at the workplace, but I would prefer a solution that is '[portable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability)' in the sense it's not depending on my hardware (vgacard|GPU-agnostic).

Comment: You are trying to overcome a window only expanding in the current monitor when you click the maximize button, correct?

Comment: @CharlieRB I would like to be able to **choose** whether to "expand in the current monitor" and "maximize to span over all monitors". Both has its situations when it is useful.

Comment: OK. That's what I thought. Can you please [edit] your question with more details like; what version of Windows are you using? What video card are you using? What have you researched/tried so far? These details will improve your chance of getting a helpful answer.

Comment: @CharlieRB thanks for pointing me in the right direction, now I edited my question to incorporate my research.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/186633/how-can-you-maximize-a-window-on-to-dual-monitors-in-windows seems to have better suggestions

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the "Maximize to desktop" function of [Ultramon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/).

This will maximize a program across multiple physical screens.

[image]

[Source](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/windows.asp)

Comment: Looks great! I wish Ultramon had aa free version. It features a lot more than I actually need - they look useful so I think it's not bloated - it's just more.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this in Google Chrome. I have two monitors, so I docked it to the right side of my right monitor and then stretched it out to the left side of my left monitor and it worked fine. This works best if the monitors are the same size and there is not a large gap between them.

Answer (score 0):

The extension of the desktop

This allows you to connect two monitors to your computer, your video card must have accordingly over 2 monitor slots. Once you have connected the two screens on your PC will appear on your desktop sync them.
Click with your right mouse button on the desktop and go to "Properties". Then select the new window, under "Settings" and click the bottom right on "Advanced".
It should appear at the top right of the driver for your graphics card. Click the box. Depending on the graphics card and driver this category will be displayed differently.
In most cases, there is a button labeled "Graphics Properties", you must click on the now. In the new window, select "Display Devices" and look for a function, the "Extended Desktop" is. If necessary, you must first have to click on a button with "Multiple Displays".
Select next to "Extended Desktop" your secondary device, confirm the action below with "OK". Your desktop should now be strecken.5 across both monitors
Setting the 2 monitors at distances

If you have problems with setting up your desktop, this could be due to your graphics card driver. Inform yourself on the manufacturer's website about you in accordance with current drivers and install them.
Even with laptops with a monitor slot in this way you can stretch the desktop across two monitors. To get from one screen to another, you must move the mouse just over the edge of the right or the left screen.
If you want to move window, you must reduce these usually before and then dragging them down.

Comment: Although this is a great explanation of how to expand the desktop, I believe they already have their desktop expanded. This is asking how to get a program window to span multiple monitors when you click `maximize`.