# Maximize a window across certain monitors instead of all monitors(e.g. two out of three) in Windows?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

Besides my laptop screen, I have two more external screens connected to my laptop. I would like to find a easier way(e.g. hotkeys) to maximumize certain progroam windows across those two external screens.

Though I learnt a way to maximize windows across all screens using [Dual Monitor Tools](http://dualmonitortool.sourceforge.net/index.html) from this quesion["maximize-a-window-on-to-dual-monitors-in-windows"](https://superuser.com/questions/186633/maximize-a-window-on-to-dual-monitors-in-windows), but it is not exactly what I expect (i.e. only onto two external monitors intead of all three ) .

Is there a way to define or customize the desired spaces/monitors where I want to supersize the active window?

Anyone knows a clue to this problem?

Comment: I know one trick to do this without any 3rd party software.  Just line up the top left corner of a floating window with the top left corner of the first monitor, then stretch/resize the bottom right corner of the window across the second monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.brianapps.net/sizer4/ It's very simple.

You can define Width, Height, Starting Monitor and Shortcut Key.

Please check mark "Allow move outside screen bounds"

Comment: Please edit your answer and declare your affiliation with this software

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).