# Display Mode Collage Missing from Graphics options

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, fullscreen, integrated-graphics

There are a few similar threads here but haven't solved my issue.

In all of the graphics options I can not find collage to make a game full-screen across two same resolution displays.

PC: Dell Inspiron 13 5310 Iris XE graphics

The laptop works great across triple monitors in extended mode. But using two monitors with same res doesn't resolve the issue.

Here is a link to similar thread and within that thread there is an older version of Intel Graphics Control Panel.

This image below is the control panel from my Windows 11 command center.

[image]

Image from another thread showing "collage"

Thank you in advance, look forward to seeing the resolution on this !

[Maximize a window on to dual monitors in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/186633/maximize-a-window-on-to-dual-monitors-in-windows/1405517#1405517)

[image]

Comment: Just a wild guess: what if hold shift and click on 2?

Comment: Thanks but no didn't give collage option

Comment: Looks like a case of a feature in an older version of Intels Control Panel and the feature isn’t applicable to your hardware. If that’s the case unfortunately there isn’t a solution to your problem since the drivers included with the older version would be applicable to your hardware nor would it support Windows 11

Answer (score 0):

There are some considerations to take into account:

Collage Display/ Combined Desktop is a feature that enables you to share one image across multiple independent displays, regardless of the panel or monitor type. The number of supported displays depends on your computer's or motherboard's capabilities. See below for more details.

1. The minimum number of displays required to use Collage Display is two.
2. The maximum number of displays for Collage Display, without an external splitter, is three.
3. Using an external DisplayPort* splitter, the maximum number of displays is four.
4. In Windows® 10 and Windows 11*, a Local Flat Panel (LFP), such as a laptop built-in display, will not count towards the number of displays when using collage mode. Only an External Flat Panel (EFP) will count towards the number of displays in collage mode.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000096140/graphics.html

Usually, the Combine Displays option is on the three dots from your display selected on the Graphics Command Center:
[Intel Graphics command center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktSgH.png)

If you're using a dock station, **make sure to use the one suggested by your PC manufacturer for your laptop.** *An OS recognizes a universal dock station* **as a secondary graphics card**. *This feature only works on* **a direct connection to your Intel graphics card**. The OS will look like a direct Intel graphics card connected to your displays using your manufacturer's PC dock station.

Hopefully, this will help you enable this feature.