# windows 7 themes - dual\multiple monitors\screens

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best multiple monitors app for Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/3004/what-is-the-best-multiple-monitors-app-for-windows-7)

Call me crazy, but I like the [Microsoft Themes in Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/personalize/themes?ocid=W7_personalizeCPL). However, the background image only seems to duplicate whatever one that it is currently on for multiple monitors. Is there any way to use the themes but have the other monitors have a random background from the current theme too rather than duplicate on both?

**EDIT #1**

I am aware of multiple monitor tools such as Display Fusion and Ultramon. Though both are nice to have, I'd like to see if there is a way to change the theme behavior using free techniques rather than commercial applications. Perhaps there is a registry change I could make? Or a script I could setup? I'm not sure, but I'd like to know and I'm willing to dig into whatever is thrown out there.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it is a duplicate. I already have Ultramon and it solves the taskbar and switching issues. However, it doesn't have changing background images like the themes do. It does however allow you do set the wallpaper for each one.

Comment: DF does Windows-7 style wallpaper changes (without any add-ons or macros).  You can even get images from a couple sources like Flickr. I used UltraMon for years, but DF now kicks its butt, it's got all the bells and whistles I've needed and 100 more. ;)

Comment: If DF can't do what you want, perhaps come back and edit your question to explain what requirement's not quite being met.

Comment: Yeah, I did look over DF (just now) and it looks like it is worth having, however, I doubt I can the boss to sign off on a paid copy when I have a copy of working copy of Ultramon ;)

Comment: @techie007 - thanks for your advice, I appreciate it. I've edited the question.

Comment: couldnt you use the tiled image as covered in the most popular answer here http://superuser.com/questions/28893/how-do-i-get-different-background-images-on-my-dual-monitors Instead of having a mega single panarama picture, have 2 seperate pictures assembled in one file?

Comment: @Psycogeek: Two files merged == single panorama

Comment: I myself wouldnt call it a panarama if it had 2 completly different pictures jammed into it, so you get 2 different pictures on 2 different monitors. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panorama

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get random backgrounds natively. You'll need to use a separate background changing program, like the free [John's Background Switcher](http://johnsadventures.com/software/backgroundswitcher/). The reason why is because Windows does not allow you to apply more than one background at a time. 3rd party programs like Display Fusion, Ultramon or John's Background Switcher get around this limitation by merging two picture files together and creating one large picture file.

If you like the pictures in the themes, you can extract them.

The theme files are merely archive files. You can open them up in Winzip or Explorer.

Comment: Wow, that John's Background Switcher is nice! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @javamonkey79: The guy is very talented. Ya, and his program rules.